# button height will not change even with -webkit-appearance: none

Tags: css, button, webkit, webkit-appearance

In real need of help here after about 3 to 4 hour of independent searching. I am building a website where it imperative I change the height of a button so iphone/ipad users get the correct style. After searching, people seem to be pointing me to the -webkit-appearance values and I've tried to impliment them with absolutly no luck. I have a codepen (https://codepen.io/osa10928/pen/awrmRG) where this was a problem too so you guys can look at that code and try and solve the problem there and hopefully I can carry yall's implimentation to my other project (I'm not at liberty to share my other projects code)

Looking at the codepen you'll see the buttons #start-button and #strict-button do not change height on iphones (or ipads I  presume, I dont't have one to check). I've tried several things like including -webkit-apperance: none on a button tag, on the individual id's in css. I've inlcuded:

```
input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=button]{
  -webkit-appearance:none; 
}
```

all to no avail. Please, could someone show me the proper implimentation of -webkit-appearance: none, or something else that will allow me to change button heights for iphone users?

**Update** Turning buttons into divs and restyling as buttons has been the best option. If anybody does have a working work around I'd love to hear it. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

you can use padding top and bottom instead of height

Comment: Should have thought of this. Will work on this occasion but is their really no other way to adjust the height?

Comment: actually spoke too soon. Paddings don't change on the iphone (iphone7 at least got to wait to check others). Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you used this -webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;

Comment: I'm running this on chrome and safari so I haven't tried moz, and I didn't know about the base "appearance: none". It's worth a shot

Comment: nope, no cigar. I think I'm just going to us a div instead and style it as a button. It sucks, cause I'm using bootstrap and now I have to add a bunch more code to get the button effects, per button :/